# Circular Dependencies in XML file

Tags: android

my android xml layout file keeps on Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
I cant figure out why? here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.amandhapola.ribbit.LoginActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_fill" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:scaleType="fitStart"
         android:src="@drawable/background" 
         android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_background"/>
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/usernameField"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/subtitle"/>

       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usernameField"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_above="@+id/signUpText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/login_button_label" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signUpText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your title to be above your subtitle, and your subtitle to be below your title:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/title" ... android:layout_above="@+id/subtitle" ... />
<TextView android:id="@+id/subtitle" ... android:layout_below="@+id/title" ... />
```

That's a circular reference: To position `title`, Android first needs to determine the position of `subtitle`. However, to position `subtitle`, it needs to determine the position of `title` first.

You need to make sure that Android can position your elements without getting into a *depencendy loop*. For example, positioning the title *at the top*, and then positioning the subtitle *below the title* would be fine.